# Remover autenticação múltipla por protocolo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, https

Olá,

Estou implementando o **MVC** com ***Asp.Net Identity***, porém, estou tendo alguns problemas...

**Cenário:** Estou me logando a partir do protocolo **HTTP**, tudo entra normalmente. Quando vou tentar acessar qualquer página com protocolo HTTPS, ele não enxerga que estou logado. Porém, o *cookie* de autenticação está lá... Pesquisei sobre o que poderia ser e descobri que o Cookie não está especificando a Flag **Secure**.

**Objetivo:** preciso me autenticar apenas com um usuário, posso forçar o **HTTPS** na hora de se logar, mas se alguém acessar alguma página pelo **HTTP** 
o sistema não enxergará que estou autenticado. Como faço para enxergar uma única autenticação tanto no **HTTP** e no **HTTPS** ?

Aqui está minha classe de Startup do Identity:

```
 public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                          validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
                          regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                },
                ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromDays(100),        
            });
        }
    }
```

Não sei onde colocar essa configuração (forçar o HTTP enxergar a autenticação do HTTPS, de um modo mais genérico).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insira no seu `Global.asax.cs` o seguinte:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (Request.IsSecureConnection)
        Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionID"].Secure = false;
}
```

Assim, seus *cookies* serão compartilhados entre requisições HTTP e HTTPS, e não apenas um ou outro.

Ou, um pouco mais moderno, você pode definir no seu `Startup.Auth.cs`, o seguinte:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    ...
    CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Never
});
```

Não acho uma boa essa configuração. O certo seria seu site estar sempre em HTTPS, mas se é necessário que funcione em ambos, as duas formas atendem.

Comment: Obrigado, já estava ficando com dor de cabeça tentando achar essa configuração.

Comment: Estava dando problemas no localhost. Verifiquei e ele gerava o cookie de autenticação do Identity sem a Flag secure, mas não enxergava em ambos os casos. Testei através do servidor externo e funcionou corretamente. Não sei se era alguma configuração específica do meu IIS Local que acabou entrando em conflito. Obrigado pela ajuda.